# c++: initiate a static array member with a static CONST member

Tags: c++, static

I'm trying to define a buffer in a base class.
This buffer should be initialized with a const value that is also defined as a static member of this class.

However, I it wont compile and I wonder what I have done wrong?

```
header file:
class Base {
  static uint8_t buf[len];   // Error. 
  static const uint32_t len;
}

src file:
const uint32_t Base::len = 100000;
uint8_t Base::buf[Base::len] = {};

The error I get is:
error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']'
```

I tried to change the Error line to be:
static uint8_t buf[Base::len] but still no good.

How to solve it and why didn't it work?

Comment: VLA are not standard C++, you should not use them in C++ even if your compiler may support it.

Comment: @akirahinoshiro there is no VLA

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to change the order of the variable declarations, otherwise you attempt to use the (yet) undeclared `len` variable in the array definition.

Secondly I highly recommend using `std::array` instead of a plain C-style array.

And lastly about your problem, which can be solved with inline initialization.

Also use the `inline` keyword to avoid separate definitions of the variables.

Put together perhaps something like this:

```
class Base {
  static inline const uint32_t len = 100000;
  static inline std::array<uint8_t, len> buf;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `len` before you use it and give it the initializer `= 100000` at the first declaration inside the class definition, not in its definition outside of the class.

This works specifically only for `const` integral types with constant expression initializers though. Generally it would be better to also replace `const` with `constexpr` which is more generally usable.

You can (probably) also remove the definition in the source file completely (assuming you don't odr-use `len` somewhere).